# Python walker that does NOT go into specific folders

Tags: python, recursion, directory, os.walk

this is my first post, so be gentle. ;)

PROBLEM: I would like to be able to use os.walk as a directory walker, but not do into certain folders. Ex:

Tree:

```
\Proj1_0
    \Load001
        \lib
        \src
\Proj2_0
    \Load001
        \lib
        \src
    \Load002
        \lib
        \src
```

I want to show the projects and loads, but not the sub-directories under loads. I can do that using the following code.

```
import os


for root, subFolders, files in os.walk('.'):
    # root does NOT contain 'Load'
    if root.find('Load') == -1:
        print "\nPROJECT: " + root + "\n"
        for folder in subFolders:
            print "    " + folder
```

However, the list is a big list, so I tried using del to but could not get it to work right and the same thing using lists, such as (which I got from another post here):

```
def my_walk(top_dir, ignore):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(top_dir):
        dirnames[:] = [
            dn for dn in dirnames
            if os.path.join(dirpath, dn) not in ignore]
        yield dirpath, dirnames, filename
list my_walk('.','Load')
```

But I could not get the return to work properly, either. I am new to Python and appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For starters, how does it not work? Does it not ignore the folders? What arguments are you giving it in `ignore`?

Comment: I suppose function os.listdir(..) should satisfy your needs :)

Comment: wow... what `dirnames[:] = ...` is doing?? as I know `dirnames[:]` make a copy of list, but suppose it should not be at the left side of `=`

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "However, the list is a big list..." what is not working about your original code?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining "big list" better. What I meant is that the top code works correctly. However, it takes forever since it keeps traversing all of the subdirs, even the ones I do not want it to traverse. Hence, why I went to using a list that I could modify...the second approach.

I will take a look at the answers below and let everyone know what I  end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
for x in os.walk('.', topdown=True):
    dirpath, dirnames, dirfiles = x
    print(dirpath, dirnames)
    dirnames[:] = filter(lambda x : not x.startswith('Load'), dirnames)
```

From `help(os.walk)`, you can modify the `names` if `topdown` is `True`, in order to restrict the search.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    dirnames[:] = [
        dn for dn in dirnames
        if ignore not in os.path.join(dirpath, dn)]
```

You want to *keep* directories where `os.path.join(dirpath, dn)` does not contain the string `ignore`.

---

By the way, you are right to use `dirnames[:]` on the left-hand side of the assignment. To prune the directories visited by `os.walk`, you have to modify the same list `dirnames`.

`dirnames[:] = ...` modifies the same list in-place.
`dirnames = ...` would redirect the name `dirnames` to a different value.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this is what I ended  up with...

```
import os,string
path = '.'
path = os.path.normpath(path)
res = []

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    depth = root[len(path) + len(os.path.sep):].count(os.path.sep)
    if depth == 2:
        # We're currently two directories in, so all subdirs have depth 3
        res += [os.path.join(root, d) for d in dirs]
        dirs[:] = [] # Don't recurse any deeper
print(res)
```

I know this is an old post, but thought I should update it with my answer. In case, anyone else finds it useful.